# Interpreting dispersion for Inverse Gaussian GAM (log linked)

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-additive-model, dispersion, underdispersion, logarithm

After reading Wood (2006), Zuur et al. (2009) and all questions related to GAMs here, I still haven't found the following:

1. Should I calculate the dispersion for an `inverse.gaussian` GAM (`link = 'log'`) with the following formula: $${\rm dispersion}=\frac{\sum({\rm residuals})^2}{N-p}$$ in which $N$ is the amount of samples and $p$ is the length of the coefficients of the GAM?
2. How to interpret the result? In my case `0.001154391`.

I understand that for Poisson and binomial distribution the dispersion is or should be 1 and that this is not the case for Gaussian families, but I don't understand what this dispersion calculation will actually tell me.

Answer (score -1):

I asked somebody in my research institute with statistical knowledge and he said that you should only calculate the dispersion for Poisson and binomial distributions.

Comment: I wonder if you may be caught up in a semantic blurring of the word "dispersion" which has a specific meaning in count-based models, but is also sometimes used as a synonym for "variability". The formula you gave in your question is a measure of **variance** specifically, which speaks to the latter concept, but not necessarily the former.